# How to echo something outside of function?

Tags: php

In the following code I want to `echo`  `green` outside of `public function`.

```
Public function lol(){
$green ="green";
}
```

for example i want to echo `$green` in the following code.

```
public function green(){
echo"this is $green";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following code :

```
function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $green ="green";
   }

public function green(){
echo"this is $green";
}
```

Place the $green variable in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `$green` in as a parameter and echo the function return value:

```
function green($green) {
  return "This is ". $green;
}

echo green('green'); //Results in: This is green
echo green('yellow'); //Results in: This is yellow
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$green;

class s {

    public function lol() {
        $GLOBALS['green'] = "green";
    }

}

$instance = new s();
$instance->lol();
echo $green;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [global variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) with `$GLOBALS`:

```
function lol(){
    $GLOBALS['green'] ="green";
}
lol();
echo $green;
```